# FIX binary decoder

Tags: market-data, fix

Not sure if this is the right question board for this -

It sounds like CME is switching their MDP platform from FAST to Simple Binary Encoding and it will be going to production soon. Does anybody know of a good (free) decoder for FIX binary? I checked with CME and they said they won't be developing one for some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An open-source reference implementation is available:

https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding

It is a Java program that will translate the XML-based data dictionary into Java, C++, and C# bindings.